# Rank of a generall linear group over a finite field

Tags: gn.general-topology, combinatorial-group-theory

What is the rank (minimal number of group generators) of the group $GL(n,F)$, when $F$ is a finite field of odd order? I found that $SL(n,F)$ is $2$, but I can't find this information.

Comment: Have you tried Googling something like "generators of finite general linear groups"?

Comment: P.S. Is there a general formula (for odd and even $q$-s)?

Comment: No, I always searched by the "rank" term. Thank you for that suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the silly question... I haven't searched the right way.
Here is the answer: [book1](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03081088908817916#.Vcx6LPlGRZs)